# Getting 'Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible.' error when testing a WCF project

Tags: c#, wcf

I was trying to test the WCF service using the SOAP UI. I was able to successfully run the service and debug the service using the SOAP UI, then, out of the blue, just by itself, without any code or config change, the service behavior changed, and was no longer able to test it

All of a sudden, once I would run the service, the strange popup would come up

[image]

And then it would display a strange error

Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata

[image]

I am honestly not sure why this popup would start appearing. I tried various things, such as killing IIS Express, rebuilding the solution, and specifying a concrete start page for a concrete service.

Any idea would be appreciated, and once again, everything was working earlier

Comment: If you are running on https, do you have a valid certificate?  Also, do you have the mex setup in the web.config?

Comment: You can try [configuring tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/configuring-tracing) to see if there are more detailed error messages.

Comment: @Mike I do have mex in the config, not sure about the certificates

Comment: @LanHuang I just tried, it is not populating the log file, but displaying the different message in a popup saying web config is wrong

Comment: I mentioned certificates, because IIS Express by default uses a certificate bound to localhost.  If you change the defaults in the config to use your hostname instead of localhost, this would cause this to happen.  The other thing I've seen happen, but typically with IIS is if you don't have the WCF features installed in the OS.  If this was working, it could be a few things, windows firewall (group policy change?), Antivirus getting in the way, misconfigured web config (changed somehow?).

Comment: Maybe turn on error reporting so the client gets the stack trace.  Kind of curious to see what error is returned to Soap UI.  WCF Client tends to hide a lot.

Comment: @Mike the solution was kind of strange, all I had to do is to highlight the .cs file, not the svc.cs file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue was rather strange. All that needs to be done is to highlight/select the cs file, NOT the svc.cs file like I was doing before